# Creating a mesh cone with exponential radius

Tags: mesh

Creating a standard cone is simple enough to do. However, the radius increases linearly along its axis. Is there a way to create one with an exponentially larger radius? For instance, suppose the radius y along the axis x is y=0.3x^2, where x>0 and <8. Can I somehow input a quadratic formula and limits somewhere to achieve this result? Or is there another alternative?

EDIT: In case it helps, I tried to subdivide the cone and change the smoothness. However, it creates the opposite effect. The higher the smoothness, the more convex it becomes. I'm trying to make it concave, but the smoothness value can't go negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via the Add Mesh Extra Objects, XYZ surface.  Enable the addon, then add mesh > Math Function > XYX math surface from the add menu.

[image]

[The parametric equations of a cone from Wolfram.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cone.html)

Here is a quick test, not sure if its the shape you want,

[image]

Comment: Yep, this looks like the right way to go. Now I just have to figure out what the right equation is...

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact math but very flexible. Bezier curve and screw modifier.
[image: Perspective and front view.]

[File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4FtOvdNAcaxSWJsRnBWSnN6Ulk)